# Como remover legenda no plot?

Tags: r, plot, legenda-de-gráfico, drc

Como posso remover a legenda que é gerada automaticamente na função `plot` do pacote `drc`?

```
plot(curva5r, ylab= "Dose (%)", xlab = "Dose (g.e.a. de glyphosate ha-1)")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que a legenda fica em cima dos dados plotados e desejo removê-la. Não adianta usar outro estilo de plot (ex: ggplot2), pois ele não suporta o pacote utilizado para ajustar os dados.

Obrigado amigos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coloque o argumento `legend=FALSE` no comando do teu gráfico:

```
plot(curva5r, ylab= "Dose (%)", xlab = "Dose (g.e.a. de glyphosate ha-1)",
  legend=FALSE)
```

---

Exemplo reprodutível com um conjunto de dados do próprio pacote `drc`:

```
library(drc)

S.alba.m1 <- drm(DryMatter~Dose, Herbicide, data = S.alba, fct = LL.4())

plot(S.alba.m1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
plot(S.alba.m1, legend=FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcus, você poderia me dizer como posso colocar o r^2 no gráfico (ex: cor( fitted(curva5r), DadosFito$controle) ^2) e como posso apagar as linhas que não são eixos (ex: as paralelas aos eixos).

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo. Caso tenha alguma pergunta extra, crie uma nova pergunta e [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) para ver como criar uma pergunta reprodutível em R.